Angular Material input - textarea with grow in flexbox
I want to let the textarea flexible grow depending on the what space is available.
So basically if I have the
<form>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width area-1">
    <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width area-2" >
    <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

I would expect that the input area grows as well. I'm aware that there exists the directive cdkTextareaAutosize but this will let the textarea grow depending on the input. Which I don't want to have.
I would like to have the textarea stretched over the whole height and not only to a small part. I want to have some kind of dynamic approach - depending where I place the component.
Stackblitz


The below CSS might work, we can just adjust so that it's always 100% based on flexbox styles and height:100%, we use display: flex and flex-grow: 1 to make the boxes fit the available space:
::ng-deep {
  .full-textarea {
    display: flex;
    mat-form-field {
      display: flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
      .mat-mdc-form-field-flex,
      .mat-mdc-form-field-infix,
      textarea {
        height: 100% !important;
      }
    }
  }
}

html
<form class="full-textarea">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width area-1">
    <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width area-2">
    <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

Stackblitz Demo

Thx for sample. I thought as well on that kind of solution. The main problem I'm having with this approach is that I need to rely on the internal Material classes. And they might change, as we've seen with Material2 and might be in front with Material3.... Honestly don't know if Material is required at all and a regular textarea it's sufficient. Anyway - thx

I've created an issue on GitHub https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28912
